# How to detect whether a person has entered a certain area in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm currently developing an application using google maps with html5 and javascript.
One of the requirements of the application is to let the user create circles on the map. After these are created (I've been using google.maps.Circle for this)

Here is my circle code..

```
var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: pos,
    radius: 200
  });
```

Basic stuff. The pos will be defined by the user pressing the screen of his/her mobile device.

My question is how do I detect when the user physically enters the circle by walking into it?
I would also need to detect that they have left the circle.

Justin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the distance between the **center of the circle** **and where the user is standing** . If that distance is **less than the radius** then the user is within the radius...

1. Google maps also offers a function : `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween`
   which takes in two latitude / longitude objects...
2. Pass one object for the user and one for the circle .
3. You can get user position with geolocation api event listeners .
4. Get the coords from the center of the circle using `cityCircle.center.lat()` and `cityCircle.center.lng()`

Now lets use this logic

```
var userposition = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

return position;

})

var user = {lat : userposition.latitude , lng : userposition.longitude}

var centerOfCircle = {lat : cityCircle.center.lat() , lng : cityCircle.center.lng() }

var distanceBetween = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(user , centerOfCircle);

if(distanceBetween <= cityCircle.radius){

    alert('You are within radius of your target')
}
```

Tip: May need  Math.floor()  to remove decimals...

Google geometry lib : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

Hope this helps..